# Pedidos de código são off topic?

Tags: suporte, escopo-do-site

Esbarrei na seguinte pergunta:

[Problema de lógica, não consigo pensar no algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295557/problema-de-l%c3%b3gica-n%c3%a3o-consigo-pensar-no-algoritmo)

Meu instinto foi sinalizar como off topic pois o autor simplesmente vomitou o enunciado do problema e está esperando uma resposta de mão beijada. Só que, antes de mandar a sinalização, percebi que a [nossa página de perguntas on topic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) não faz quaisquer ressalvas quanto a pedidos de código pronto.

Por outro lado, [a página do SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) deixa claro que perguntas assim são off topic lá (item 3 da segunda lista).

O meu instinto de marcar como off topic se deve ao fato de eu estar acostumado com as regras do SO gringo.

A minha dúvida é: O nosso SO está aberto para pedidos de código pronto?

Comment: Sim, são fora do escopo, a não ser que o objetivo do SO tenha sido distorcido, era de ajudar no aprendizado e resolução de problemas de quem tem interesse em aprender mas emperrou em determinado problema, não fazer trabalho de escola ou dar manutenção gratuita a pessoas preguiçosas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São *off-topic* sim. Sei lá porque no nosso não tem essa parte. Ou sei, pra confundir mais e criar dificuldade de gerenciamento. Lá diz:

> um problema específico de programação

Isto não é específico. Se for pedindo um código bem específico, acho que pode é válido, geralmente uma expressão ou pouco mais que isso. Não tem medida exata, mas se tem várias linhas me parece que é pedido de código pronto.

Se tem uma descrição enorme e pergunta como faz, me parece que é um pedido de código pronto.

Eu acho que alguma coisa assim pode ser aceita, mas precisa ser muito bem feita. Em geral as pessoas que pedem isso não conseguem fazer bem feito.

Ali tem cara de ser o pedido de resolver um exercício da escola. Não importa se é ou não. Isto em si não é um problema, respondemos sobre dúvidas que as pessoas possuem quando estão fazendo um exercício. O problema é pedir tudo, não ter uma dúvida específica, não demonstrar esforço.

Comment: Não sei se precisa de motivo específico, ampla demais e não clara costuma dar conta.